# How to start a cover letter during submission?

Tags: publications, paper-submission

I'm submitting a paper to an Elsevier journal. One of the submission steps seems to be writing a cover letter to the journal office. They say that:

> Please enter any comments you would like to send to the Journal
>   Office.

In order to start the cover letter, I wanted to write:

> Dear editor

but after googling the sample cover letters, I found out that I should write the editor's name. But the question is that **which editor?**

The journal has one editor-in-chief and multiple other editors. Which one's name should I mention? Will the editor-in-chief investigate the submission or who?

Should I use another terms instead of "dear ..."?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't obsess over it. *Dear Editor* is fine unless you have already corresponded with them. In fact, if you direct it to an individual by name it might well be handled by someone else - especially in a large organization.

Eventually you may get the name of someone who is responsible for managing your paper. Then you can be a bit more personal.

Comment: Sorry I became a little hesitant. Does "Please enter any comments you would like to send to the Journal Office." means I should write my cover letter? or it requires something else?

Comment: It doesn't sound exactly like a cover letter. But saying something about the paper will help the editors route it to the appropriate people for evaluation. In particular, they need to choose an appropriate subject editor to give it a quick evaluation and then to find reviewers.

Comment: What should I write about the paper?

Comment: Field, subfield, and such. A sort of classification. If they need more than you write, they will likely ask.